# checkspell textbox words onkeyup event

Tags: php, javascript

I have a textbox. What I want is when user enters a word in that textbox, it should call `onkeyup` function and in the function we should check if spelling is correct or not.

If it is correct we don't do anything if its not we should display an alert message and remove all text from the textbox. Please tell what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Remove *all* text for *one* spelling mistake? That sounds like a painful UI...unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: The OP says the textbox will contain 'a word'.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it

```
function checkWord()
{
    var arr = ....;
    var word = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    var found = false;

    for (var item in arr)
    {
        if(item == word)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        document.getElementById('textbox').value = "";
        alert("Some message");
    }
}
```

Add `checkWord` to the onkeyup attribute of you textbox, though I think you'd be better using `onchange` or `onblur`.

The `arr` variable should be written to hold an array of correctly spelt words.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i was actually looking for something that could spell check also? I can not put in 160 thousand words in that array that would slow down the app.